# Issue when using firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged accross two pages

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having a small problem with two html pages which used to work in the past.

First, I have a login page (login.html) containing this kind of code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    window.open("main.html",'_self');
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    prompt for login ....
    ......
  }
});
```

Second, I also have this page (main.html) containing this sort of code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    do serious work ....
    ......
  } else {
    // Let us double check:
    let theUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (!theUser) {
        // No user is signed in.
        window.open("login.html",'_self');
    }
    // We need some patience :)
    ......
  }
});
```

Once a user is logged in, things are supposed to go to main.html; and this is how it used to work. But now, for some unknown reason; when I log in, even though I have provided my credentials, the flow goes to main.html (as it should) but immediately bounces back to login.html.

I have been able to check that the block (in the main.html):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {...}
```

does not detect me as logged in. Why is that?

P.S.
I have verified that my domain is added in the list of Authorized domains in the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue. I narrowed it down to Chrome. It seems to think that Chrome isn't allowed to save cookies when it is (I checked the settings). Might be an issue with a recent Chrome update? Just as a sanity check, try it on Firefox and let me know if that works. It did for me.

UPDATE: This is what I get back when I console log the error

```
{code: "auth/web-storage-unsupported", message: "This browser is not 
supported or 3rd party cookies and data may be disabled.", a: null}
```

UPDATE 2: Strangely enough, I disabled cookies, tried and it failed. Re-allowed cookies (just as it was initially) and it works now. I would suggest capturing this error and prompting users to ensure they check their browser settings. I'm going to do this in my app.

Comment: I am not using Chrome, but FireFox.

Comment: Try catching and console.loggimg amy errors on your login function call.